# Unable to query using a pointer using Android SDK

Tags: parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I am trying to run a query using `com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0` version of the parse android SDK. I am creating a query on the local storage and using `ParseQuery$whereMatchesQuery()` method to match a column storing pointer to another class in my database. The code that I have is the following:

```
ParseQuery<PracticeSessionDetails> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(PracticeSessionDetails.class);
query.fromLocalDatastore();
query.ignoreACLs();
query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

ParseQuery courseQuery = new ParseQuery("Course");
courseQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId",courseId);
query.whereMatchesQuery("course", courseQuery);
```

When I run the `query` using `query.getFirst()`, I do not get anything retrieved from the local storage. I have already checked running the `courseQuery` separately and it fetches me `Course` object that I need. Is this a known issue? I proceeded with this way by getting help from [this post](https://parse.com/questions/query-with-filter-on-pointer-field).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing query while storing pointer to another class in your database. Use following code to resolve your problem:

```
   ParseQuery<PracticeSessionDetails> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(PracticeSessionDetails.class);
   query.fromLocalDatastore();
   query.ignoreACLs();
   query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

   ParseQuery<ParseObject> courseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Course");
   courseQuery.whereMatchesQuery("course", query);
```